Mockito does not properly mock GetxController lifecycle methods FLUTTER
Description: When using Mockito to mock a GetxController, lifecycle methods like onStart are not stubbed, leading to MissingStubError. This makes it difficult to test widgets or functionality that depend on Get.put or lifecycle hooks of the controller.
Reproduction Steps:

Create a GetxController class.
Mock the controller using Mockito's GenerateMocks way.
Call Get.put(YourMockedController) in your test.

Expected Behavior: The mocked controller should integrate with Get.put seamlessly, and no MissingStubError should occur when onStart or other lifecycle methods are accessed.
Actual Behavior: The test throws a MissingStubError for lifecycle methods such as onStart.
Sample Code:
class CounterController extends GetxController {
  RxInt counter = 0.obs;
}

@GenerateMocks([CounterController])
void main() {
  final MockCounterController mockCounterController = MockCounterController();

  test('Mockito mocking GetxController issue', () {
    Get.put(mockCounterController); // Throws MissingStubError
  });
}


https://psuedopolymath.hashnode.dev/getx-and-flutter-widget-testing-how-to-use-mock-getx-controller might be helpful to you

I tried that solution, But when I try to put a controller like this:
      MockCounterController(),
    );
    when(mockCounterController.count).thenReturn(1);```

Always the below exception is getting thrown:

The following _TypeError was thrown running a test:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int'

No matter what type I return in stub, It always null
